# How to unregister an Event Source under Application Log using Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, event-log

I want to unregister an Event source.
I am using following Powershell command:

```
Remove-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "My Event Source"
```

But I am getting following error:

[image: Event Source Error]

Can somebody help me to understand what's going wrong?

Comment: `Get-Help Remove-EventLog` shows that the parameters `LogName` and `Source` are from two different parameter sets - you can't use both at the same time.

Comment: But while creating Event source under Application log I use both of them in the following command:
New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "My Event Source"

Comment: It's a different cmdlet and so has different parameter sets. For `Remove-EventLog` you can use one or the other, but not both. I suspect you'd need to use `Source` only.

Comment: OK, if I use only `Source` then it will delete the Event Source completely. What if I want to unregister it from only Application log and will keep using it under other Event logs e.g. System?

Comment: Did you use `New-EventLog` twice, once for Application and once for System? If so, i think the only way would be to remove the Event Source completely and then re-add it to System.

Comment: No,I didn't use it twice.I just asked. I think it can not be used twice because when I run the following command:
`PS C:\windows\system32> New-EventLog -LogName System -Source "My Event Source"
New-EventLog : The "My Event Source" source is already registered on the "localhost" computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-EventLog -LogName System -Source "My Event Source"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewEventLogCommand`